# ListView Refresh causes update of header view

Tags: java, c#, android, listview, xamarin

I have a simple list view with a custom adapter.

With `AddHeaderView`, I have added a `Map` to the top of my `ListView` but whenever I refresh my adapter, the map flickers. For example, when I delete my items before/during a refresh, or when I add my items after the refresh.

This bothers me because I have a lot of dynamic updates so the map flickers every say, 10 seconds.

I had a marker refresh on every update. I removed it but it still flickers. I've also tried reusing an adapter but still no luck..

Is there any way to avoid this behavior on a list view?

Comment: if your listview is changing very frequently, then you should add that map just above the listview instead of as a header to listview . Make use of negative margin to avoid any separation between the two views

Comment: i've tried that, but i want the map to scroll along when i scroll down in the list.. :(

Comment: Then I would have asked you to put the two in a scrolview and manage the scroll of  views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.make scroll view as parentview

2.add map and listview in scrollview

use this method in your activity

```
public static void getListViewSize(ListView myListView) {
        ListAdapter myListAdapter = myListView.getAdapter();
        if (myListAdapter == null) {
            //do nothing return null
            return;
        }
        //set listAdapter in loop for getting final size
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int size = 0; size < myListAdapter.getCount(); size++) {
            View listItem = myListAdapter.getView(size, null, myListView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
      //setting listview item in adapter
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = myListView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (myListView.getDividerHeight() * (myListAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        myListView.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

3. Pass listview object as parameter of above method

Comment: This is accepted answer, but  this has huge performance problem as it calculate view heights and create views multiple times, not reusing them. So developers beware before using this.